# wookmark modification and li side by side and under each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i'm using wookmark plugin for my project and i need to load more items when the V scroll reach to the bottom.
plugin url : http://www.wookmark.com/jquery-plugin
scroll function that i use :

```
function _scroll() {
    var v = false;
    $(document).scroll(function(e) {
        var t = document.height - (window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight);
        if ((t <= 20) && ( !v)) {
            v = true;
            $.ajax({ type:"POST",
            data: {type:$("#type").val(),id:$("#pid").val(),lid:$("#lid").val()},
            async:true,
            cache:false,
            url:"fetchMore.php?v=18",
            success: function(d) {
                var t = d.split('{@}');
                if (parseInt($("#lid").val()) != t[1]) { 
                    $("#tiles").append(t[0]);
                    $("#lid").val(t[1]);
                    applyLayout();
                }
                v = false;
            } });
        }
    });
}
```

and the applylayout function:

```
function applyLayout() {
          $('#tiles').imagesLoaded(function() {
            // Destroy the old handler
            if ($handler.wookmarkInstance) {
              $handler.wookmarkInstance.clear();
            }
            $handler = $('#tiles li');
            $handler.wookmark(options);
          });
}
```

Finally my options and sort functions:

```
function comparatorId(a, b) {
          return $(a).attr("id") > $(b).attr("id") ? -1 : 1;
        }
function _Animate() {
     $('#tiles').imagesLoaded(function() {
          options = {
          autoResize: true,
          container: $('#main'),
          offset: 2,
          itemWidth: 210,
          comparator: comparatorId,
          direction: 'right',
          fillEmptySpace: false
        };
        $handler = $('#tiles li');
        $handler.wookmark(options);
      });
}
```

The problem is:
when i'm going to load more the items are randomly re-sorting just like there is no comparatorId function ..
is there any solution ?
if there is no solution ..
how can i do a ul li tags like this layout ?
i can put them side by side but i want them to be side by side + under each other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've solved the problem..
it's just by putting data-id="{ID}"  tag for li and remove all class(es)